# Matching columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if there is a way to display a set of matching or distinct data.. like, say i have three tables,

```
tbl_1-
ip  |isp    |infection
----------------------
1   |aaaa   |malware
2   |bbbb   |malware
3   |cccc   |ddos
3   |cccc   |trojan
4   |dddd   |ddos

tbl_2-
ip  |isp    |infection
----------------------
1   |aaaa   |malware
3   |cccc   |ddos
4   |dddd   |trojan
5   |eeee   |trojan
6   |ffff   |other

tbl_3-
ip  |isp    |infection
----------------------
1   |aaaa   |ddos
6   |ffff   |
2   |bbbb   |other
```

and to get a result as follows,

```
Result i need-
ip  |isp    |infection
----------------------
1   |aaaa   |malware
1   |aaaa   |ddos
2   |bbbb   |malware
2   |bbbb   |other
3   |cccc   |ddos
3   |cccc   |trojan
4   |dddd   |ddos
4   |dddd   |trojan
5   |eeee   |trojan
6   |ffff   |other
6   |ffff   |
```

The problem is i dont know what methodology to use for this scenario, i used this query a `full join` ,

```
SELECT a. * , b. * , c. *
FROM tbl_1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_2 b
USING ( ip, isp, infection )
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_3 c
USING ( ip, isp, infection )
UNION
SELECT a. * , b. * , c. *
FROM tbl_2 b
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_1 a
USING ( ip, isp, infection )
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_3 c
USING ( ip, isp, infection )
UNION
SELECT a. * , b. * , c. *
FROM tbl_3 c
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_1 a
USING ( ip, isp, infection )
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_2 b
USING ( ip, isp, infection )
```

but this gives the result in a different way,

```
Result i get-
ip  |isp    |infection  ip  |isp    |infection  ip  |isp    |infection
----------------------  ----------------------  ----------------------
1   |aaaa   |malware    1   |aaaa   |malware    NULL|NULL   |NULL
NULL|NULL   |NULL       NULL|NULL   |NULL       1   |aaaa   |ddos   
2   |bbbb   |malware    NULL|NULL   |NULL       NULL|NULL   |NULL   
NULL|NULL   |NULL       NULL|NULL   |NULL       2   |bbbb   |other
3   |cccc   |ddos       3   |cccc   |ddos       NULL|NULL   |NULL
3   |cccc   |trojan     NULL|NULL   |NULL       NULL|NULL   |NULL
4   |dddd   |ddos       NULL|NULL   |NULL       NULL|NULL   |NULL
NULL|NULL   |NULL       4   |dddd   |trojan     NULL|NULL   |NULL
NULL|NULL   |NULL       5   |eeee   |trojan     NULL|NULL   |NULL       
NULL|NULL   |NULL       6   |ffff   |other      NULL|NULL   |NULL       
NULL|NULL   |NULL       NULL|NULL   |NULL       6   |ffff   |
```

PLEASE help me on this one, i want to display the data in 3 columns only..

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple `UNION`

```
SELECT ip, isp, infection FROM tbl_1
UNION
SELECT ip, isp, infection FROM tbl_2
UNION
SELECT  ip, isp, infection FROM tbl_3
ORDER BY IP
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f122e/3)

Comment: ohhh.. :P thanks for pointing me out...i guess everything was getting complicated, n missed these solutions , thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (
        SELECT * FROM tbl_1 
        UNION 
        SELECT * FROM tbl_2 
        UNION 
        SELECT * FROM tbl_3
       ) AS t
ORDER BY ip, isp
```

Comment: Why an inner query when a simple UNION between all 3 tables would give him the result he needs?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply this also works, once you add an alias to the select statement as `SELECT * FROM (...) AS A ORDER BY ip. isp` ...thank you very much :) :) much appreciated

Comment: @agarhy Inner query makes no difference here as far as performance goes, but I felt the ORDER BY clause at the end of the union makes the intent more clear

Comment: @nawfal I see what you mean. I was just curious about the choice of syntax not performance.

Answer (score 1):

You should `UNION` the three tables and do `GROUP BY` to remove the duplicates:

```
SELECT ip, isp, infection 
FROM tbl_1

UNION

SELECT ip, isp, infection 
FROM tbl_2

UNION

SELECT  ip, isp, infection 
FROM tbl_3

GROUP BY ip, isp, infection

ORDER BY IP
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the most elegant solution, but would something like this work? (assuming I have the syntax correct...can't test it at the moment):

```
SELECT * FROM ((SELECT * FROM tbl_1) UNION (SELECT * FROM tbl_2) UNION (SELECT * FROM tbl_3)) ORDER BY isp DESC, infection DESC;
```

Comment: yea, yours also gives the output i need once i add an alias to the outer select :) thank you very much :)